# Python: как задать горячие клавиши в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, lambda, hotkeys

Я пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет читать текстовый файл с соответствием горячая **`клавиша:символ`** и задавать горячие клавиши для этих символов:

```
import keyboard
import tkinter.messagebox as mb

with open('hotkeys.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as hotkeys:
    hotkeys = hotkeys.readlines()
c = 0

for hotkey in hotkeys:
    c += 1
    hotkey = hotkey.replace('\n', '')
    hotkey = hotkey.split(':')
    try:
        keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey[0], lambda: keyboard.write(hotkey[1]))
    except:
        mb.showerror('Ошибка', f'Неверный формат записи в конфигурационном файле: строка {c}.')
        exit()

keyboard.wait('ctrl+alt+x')
```

Содержимое **hotkeys.txt**:

```
alt+1:!
alt+2:@
alt+3:#
alt+4:$
```

Но при запуске такого скрипта всем горячим клавишам почему-то назначается то, что написано в последний строке. То есть я ожидаю, что при нажатии **`alt+1`** будет напечатан **`!`**, при нажатии **`alt+2`** -  **`@`** и так далее.

На практике при нажатии любой комбинации **`alt+1 - 4`** печатается **`$`** (то есть то, что прописано только для **`alt+4`**).

Пробовал задавать горячие клавиши без цикла, вручную - всё работает. Похоже, проблема именно в цикле.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи, почему такое странное поведение?

Comment: Согласен. Я написал в файле hotkeys.txt alt+1:один alt+2:два alt+3:три alt+4:четыре  и всё время получается четыре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import keyboard
import tkinter.messagebox as mb

with open('hotkeys.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as hotkeys:
    hotkeys = hotkeys.readlines()
#print(f'{hotkeys}')  
c = 0

for hotkey in hotkeys:
    c += 1
    hotkey = hotkey.replace('\n', '')
    hotkey = hotkey.split(':')
    #print(f'hotkey = {hotkey}') #
    try:
        z = keyboard.add_hotkey(
            hotkey[0], 
            
#            lambda: keyboard.write(hotkey[1])
            lambda h1=hotkey[1]: keyboard.write(h1)                 # !!!  <----      
            
        )
    except:
        mb.showerror(
            'Ошибка', 
            f'Неверный формат записи в конфигурационном файле: строка {c}.')
        exit()

keyboard.wait('ctrl+alt+x')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это, кажется, работает. Не могли бы вы объяснить, почему? Если я делаю то же самое без цикла:
```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+1', lambda: keyboard.write('!'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+2', lambda: keyboard.write('"'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+3', lambda: keyboard.write('#'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+4', lambda: keyboard.write('$'))
```
Всё срабатывает без введения дополнительных переменных.

Comment: @Futyn потому-что в вашем случае при выходе из цикла `hotkey[1]` равно последнему значению, которое присваивается и всем предыдущим `hotkey[1]`

Comment: @Futyn получается, что я ответил неверно. Значит, всё таки все функции разные но все они принимают на вход ```hotkey[1]``` который на выходе из цикла принимает значение ```$```. В программе Ника ```hotkey[1]``` сохраняется в переменной ```h1```, и при выходе из цикла ```hotkey[1]``` изменяет своё значение, но переменные внутри лямбды сохраняют те значения, которые получили при первой инициализации

Comment: @alex да, теперь вы правильно рассуждаете.

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть предположение, но думаю что оно верное

Для понимания, надо представить себе участок памяти, размером в 4 байта

При первом выполнении метода `add_hotkey` в ячейку памяти с адресом 1 записывается функция `lambda` которая выводит `!`

Если мы уменьшим файл `hotkeys.txt` до одной строки то мы увидим, что это именно так и всё работает !

Но проблема в том, что при следующем шаге в ячейку памяти с адресом 1 записывается уже другая `lambda` которая выводит `@`

Если мы оставим в файле `hotkeys.txt` две строки, то мы увидим, что `alt+1` и `alt+2` выводят одно и тоже, а именно - символ `@`

Это произошло потому что первый хоткей у нас указывает на адрес 1 и второй хоткей тоже указывает на адрес 1, вот только в адресе 1 уже записана вторая `lambda`, а первая - потерялась ( была перезаписана ).

Таким образом, после выполнения всего кода все хоткеи `alt+1,2,3,4` указывают на последнюю лямбду и поэтому все выводят `$`

А вот как сделать так, чтобы лямбды не перезаписывали друг друга, а размещались в разных областях памяти - я не знаю, пусть эксперты подскажут